# Digital asset management software recommendations?

Tags: software-recommendation, resource-recommendations, asset-management

I'm looking for recommendations for software to help manage my large collection of purchased icons and other image assets. I'm sure there must be software of the sort I'm looking for, but I haven't found anything really suitable yet. I'm looking for something that runs on Windows and is reasonably priced (say no more than $200-$300).

My icon collection is a number of different sets (styles) of icons broken into topical groupings. Each icon typically consists of a master vector image combined with the icon rendered (and hand-tweaked) into perhaps 6-8 bitmap sizes (i.e. 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 64x64, etc.) and each of them in normal, hot, and disabled forms. A base icon set may well have another 4-6 complete variations with overlaid symbols (like a "+" or "-" on top of a person icon for add and remove). So each logical icon can represent 50-60 files. There's over 2 million files in 2000 folders totaling 230 GB where I'm storing these.

I want to be able to search for icons by name, collection, keyword, format, size, etc. I want see fast thumbnails of matching files so I can select an appropriate image. I want to see what the source and license for the image is (purchased, creative commons, etc.).

Basically a database for icons/images with an understanding of derivative versions of assets.

I've found a couple of asset management programs but they seem to be designed for photographers and not really helpful for what I'm looking for. And the large number of files will likely overwhelm simplistic solutions. My Google mojo seems to be off today because I can't figure out the right keywords to find what I'm looking for. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/4849/85 — currently not much of a help for your specific case, but if you have Adobe Bridge already lying on your HDD, you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 2):

[Extensis Portfolio](http://www.extensis.com/en/products/portfolio8-5/overview.jsp) is probably the best out there as a single-user DAM. Portfolio has been around for a long time, and is a very mature product. It's $200, but there's a free trial so you can test drive it and see if it will meet your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use [TACTIC](http://community.southpawtech.com/community/) it's highly scalable (spread across multiple server) and come in Team version with a simple double-click install for small teams.

It relies on the web-technology, and could be used for project and task management as well. And can be used to design custom project schema and workflow pipelines.

It's open-source and free to download and use.

I would recommend you use the [VMware Image](http://community.southpawtech.com/downloads) version which comes pre-configured with sample asset libraries and project templates to get you started with, plus system images are quite portable and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that a software with the price tag of $200-$300, such as Extensis Portfolio, would actually crumble under the 2 million files. Those systems are really for small photography shops or marketing departments that handle files around ten thousands.

I would say that you may want to rely on [Google Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) or simply your operating system. Especially in this case a Mac would be very helpful as the Spotlight search is very powerful and the quick preview feature will give you most of what you want. You can also tag your images with metadata and use nice descriptive names.